# Android Different Menu Resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-menu

Doe's Android support multiple menu folder (e.g. like /drawable-hdpi and /drawable-mdpi)? If so what types are supported (land, xhdpi, swXXXdp)?

P.S. Sorry for such a goofy question...

Edit 1: For example I have different layouts. Depending on that I can have different menu resources, no? As a start it would be nice to have sooch folders:

- res/menu
- res/menu-land
- res/menu-xhdpi
- res/menu-xhdpi-land
- res/menu-sw600dp

The first two work fine... but when I try to add the other ones the app work instable on different devices.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question, but please give us an example of how you would want to use such a thing so we get a more clear idea of what you exactly are searching for.

Comment: The problem is that when I add menu-xhdpi folder all devices take the menu specs from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. even in portrait and landscape modus:

menu-land-mdpi
menu-port-mdpi

menu-land-hdpi
menu-port-hdpi

menu-land-xhdpi
menu-port-xhdpi

Answer (score 1):

**yes**. Don't see any point not to support it, documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) provides no restrictions on it (I myself at least have used -land qualifier)

Answer (score 1):

The menu can be used like layout folder, you can add menu-land, menu-port ... also, you can use specific menu for multi langue, like menu-fr, menu-en to rearrange items based on phone language...